# Not generating BuildConfig when compiling with gradle command line

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm trying to assemble an apk for a flavor by executing something like:

```
gradlew installFlavourNameDebug
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Task :app:compileFlavourNameDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

The point is that gradle doesn't seems to be generating the BuildConfig which I defined in gradle's app file, defining on the Flavour's definition something like:

```
buildConfigField "String", "Foo", "\"value\""
```

According to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#DebugMode) this should be the way, but I don't have any clue of the reason this isn't working. Note that when I build the app with Android Studio by clicking 'Run' there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you run the gradlew with a --stacktrace --debug to get more information? Usually I set the parameters in this way :

```
buildConfigField("String", "PARAMETER_NAME", '"test"')
```

Comment: I tested it and verified a that in the documentation https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips#share-custom-fields-and-resource-values-with-your-app-code they define it like that, but I still have the same problem. And yes I tried with --stacktrace

Comment: You can add more details about the error? The stacktrace error?

Answer (score 0):

I answer myself. After performing a clean of the project in Android Studio "gradlew installFlavourNameDebug" worked properly, but I guess that executing "gradlew clean" 
should work ok also.